# How can I improve massively classification report of one class using ensemble model?

Tags: python, nlp, imbalanced-data

I have a dataset including

{0: 6624, 1: 75} 0 for nonobservational sentences and 1 for observational sentences. (basically, I annotate my sentences using Named Entity Recognition, If there is a specific entity like DATA, TIME, LONG (coordinate) I put label 1)

Now I want to make a model to classify them, the best model (CV =3 FOR ALL) that I made is the ensembling model of

```
clf= SGDClassifier()
trial_05=Pipeline([("vect",vec),("clf",clf)])
```

which has:

```
                  precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00      6624
           1       0.73      0.57      0.64        75

   micro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      6699
   macro avg       0.86      0.79      0.82      6699
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      669
```

```
[[6611   37]
 [  13   38]]
```

and this model which used resampled sgd for classifcation

```
                  precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      0.92      0.96      6624
           1       0.13      1.00      0.22        75

   micro avg       0.92      0.92      0.92      6699
   macro avg       0.56      0.96      0.59      6699
weighted avg       0.99      0.92      0.95      6699
```

```
[[6104    0]
 [ 520   75]]
```

As you see the problem in both cases is class 1, but in forst one we have fairly good precision and f1 score versus in the second one we have a very good recall

So I decided to use ensemble model using both in this way:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier#create a dictionary of our models
estimators=[("trail_05",trial_05), ("resampled", SGD_RESAMPLED_Model)]#create our voting classifier, inputting our models
ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators, voting='hard')
```

now I have this result:

```
                precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.99      1.00      1.00      6624
           1       0.75      0.48      0.59        75

   micro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      6699
   macro avg       0.87      0.74      0.79      6699
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      6699
```

```
[[6612   39]
 [  12   36]]
```

As you the ensembe model has better precision regarding to class 1,but worse recall and f1 socre which caused to worse confusion matrix regarding classed 1 (36 TP vs 38 TP for class 1)

MY aim is to improve TP for class one (f1 score, recall for class 1)

what do you recommend to improve TP for class one (f1score, recall for class 1?
generaly do you have any idea regarding my workflow?

I have tried parameter tuning, it i does not improve sgd model.

Comment: Sounds like you should just run NER on the sentences at inference time, and classify them as 1 if the sentence has the entities you look for?

Comment: thank you for the response, that correct I put zero if all LONG,DATE,TIME entity form NER is in the sentence.  Now I made labeled data in this way. I made a classification model. I want to improve that

Comment: @Shanteshwar Inde, do you have any idea how can I solve this have better classification result for class 1 after ensemble?

Comment: @Ines Montan I would be happy with your comments regarding this, many thanks

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew
 any idea would be great!